# Java : How to display a label inside a Jframe component

Tags: java, swing, label, jframe

I try do display a text at the bottom of the container (JFrame) but it doesn't appear ....

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class Peintre extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener {
    private int valeurX ;
    private int valeurY;
    
    public Peintre() {
        super("Programme simple de dessin");
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Tirer sur la souris pour dessiner");
        label.setForeground(Color.PINK);
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        add(label,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setSize(700, 500);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.fillOval(valeurX, valeurY, 15, 15);
    }
    
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        valeurX = e.getX();
        valeurY = e.getY();

        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Peintre();

    }

}
```

I tried :

- Check width and height of the container
- set position of the label inside the frame
- change the color and font-family for visibility

I wanna display multiple characters at the bottom of the frame

Comment: it doesn't appear because you have overridded `paint` and not called super.paint

Comment: For flexibility, you probably should be subclassing JPanel instead of JFrame.

Comment: As a general recommendation, avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers, like `JFrame`, instead prefer overriding `paintComponent` of normal containers, like `JPanel`.  Also see [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to get a better understanding of how painting works in Swing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been stated, you've overridden a method from the parent class, but failed to either take over it's responsibility or call it's super implementation (ie `paint`).

As a general recommendation, avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers, like `JFrame`, instead prefer overriding `paintComponent` of normal containers, like `JPanel`.  Also see [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to get a better understanding of how painting works in Swing.

Further, avoid extending from top level containers, you're not adding any new functionality the class, instead prefer composition over extension.  In particular, `JFrame` has a complex component hierarchy, which could interfere with what ever was painted by the `paint` method randomly.

Also, in your current code, it would be possible for your paint to interfere with the label, you might want this, you might not, but it's a consideration to keep in mind.

The following example separates the label from the paint workflow, so it's not for the two to interfere with each other.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
    
    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    
    protected class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new PaintPane());
            add(new JLabel("You can't paint over me"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }
    }
    
    protected class PaintPane extends JPanel { 

        private Point dragPoint;
        
        public PaintPane() {
            MouseAdapter adapter = new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    dragPoint = e.getPoint();
                    repaint();
                }
            };
            addMouseMotionListener(adapter);
        }
        
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (dragPoint == null) {
                return;
            }
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.fillOval(dragPoint.x - 8, dragPoint.y - 8, 16, 16);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have overriden

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
```

of your JFrame. That means that any components you have added to it will not paint anymore. Call `super.paint(g);` as a first operation in your paint implementation to invoke the JFrame implementation, and then draw your oval.

In general you have to be careful about overriding methods in swing. Always check if they are not doing something important before doing so.

Comment: Okaay  it got resolved ! . So by doing super.paint(g ) it calls the paint method of Jframe class to perform its own painting operations such as background and  any other components present in the frame . Once it's done , now we can draw on the frame .